# jQuery slider navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a jQuery slider that would automatically change slides every 1s, but when i added sliding bullets (stylized divs) It started malfunctioning. I tried everything to fix it, but i couldn't figure out what's wrong, i hope you could do what i failed to do

If you didn't understand the description, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fxk1fxy9/

PS: The slider itself works fine, and if i don't hover the "bullets" there is no issue

Here is my code

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.pic').hide();
            i=1;
            function slider(){

            $('#pic-'+i).fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0',function(){
            i=i+1;if(i==6){i=1;}slider();

            });

            }
            slider();
            });
            function show1(){
            $('.pic').hide();
            $('#pic-1').fadeIn('1').delay(1000);
            }
            function show2(){
            $('.pic').hide();
            $('#pic-2').fadeIn('1').delay(1000);
            }
            function show3(){
            $('.pic').hide();
            $('#pic-3').fadeIn('1').delay(1000);
            }
            function show4(){
            $('.pic').hide();
            $('#pic-4').fadeIn('1').delay(1000);
            }
            function show5(){
            $('.pic').hide();
            $('#pic-5').fadeIn('1').delay(1000);
            }
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider">


        <!-- Slide 1 -->
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="options">
                    <div class="option" onmouseover="show1();">
                        <div class="o-rank">
                            <h1> 1 </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-text">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-button">
                            <a href="#"> > </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" onmouseover="show2();">
                        <div class="o-rank">
                            <h1> 2 </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-text">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-button">
                            <a href="#"> > </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" onmouseover="show3();">
                        <div class="o-rank">
                            <h1> 3 </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-text">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-button">
                            <a href="#"> > </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" onmouseover="show4();">
                        <div class="o-rank">
                            <h1> 4 </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-text">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-button">
                            <a href="#"> > </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" onmouseover="show5();">
                        <div class="o-rank">
                            <h1> 5 </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-text">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-button">
                            <a href="#"> > </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pictures">
                    <div class="pic" id="pic-1">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" id="tes-1" class="tes" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic" id="pic-2">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" id="tes-2"  class="tes">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic" id="pic-3">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg" id="tes-3"  class="tes">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic" id="pic-4">
                        <img src="img/4.jpg" id="tes-4"  class="tes">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic" id="pic-5">
                        <img src="img/5.jpg" id="tes-5"  class="tes">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; border:0; box-sizing:border-box;font: inherit;}

.slider{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#111;
}
.slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}

.options{
  width:10%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
}

.option{
  width:700px;
  height:18%;
  margin-bottom:9%;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all .5s ease;
}
.option:hover{
    background:#000;
}
.o-rank{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#34495e;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:30px;
}
.o-rank h1{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
}
.o-logo{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.o-logo img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.o-title{
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.o-title h1{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:90px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.o-text{
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
.o-text p{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:left;
}
.o-button{
  width:60px;
  height:40px;
  background:#34495e;
  float:right;
  margin-top:25px;
  text-align:center;
}
.o-button a{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:24px;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:40px;
}
.pictures{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:10;
}
#pic-1, #pic-2, #pic-3, #pic-4, #pic-5{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.pic img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.p-hov{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    z-index:999;
}
#pic-h-1, #pic-h-2, #pic-h-3, #pic-h-4, #pic-h-5{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute
}

.pic-h img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

/* Responsive */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 800px) {
  .slider{
    height:220px;
  }
  .option{
    width:300px;
  }
  .o-rank{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:4px;
  }
  .o-rank h1{
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:15px;
  }
  .o-logo{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:7.5px;
    margin-left:6px;
  }
  .o-title{
    width:70px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
  }
  .o-title h1{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:8px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:40px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  .o-text{
    width:135px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
  }
  .o-text p{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:8px;
    text-align:left;
  }
  .o-button{
    width:30px;
    height:15px;
    background:#34495e;
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .o-button a{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    top:-12px;
  }
}
```

Comment: @downvoter would be nice to state the reason of the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.... you need to be able to pause the slideshow if you want hover effects to work, you also should abstract those mouseover events into a hover handler so you don't have to define individual functions or element attributes.... try something like this

```js
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pic').hide();
        slider_delay = false;
        
        function slider(hover) {
            var current = $('.pic.active');
            var next;
            if(!hover){
                next = current.next();
            }else{
                next=$('#pic-'+hover.attr('id').split('_')[1]);
            }
            if (next.length == 0) next = $('#pic-1');
            current.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(next).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    window.clearTimeout(slider_delay);
                    if (!hover) slider_delay = window.setTimeout(slider, 1000);
                });
            });
        }
        $('.option').hover(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(slider_delay);
            slider($(this));
        },
        function(){
            window.clearTimeout(slider_delay);
            slider_delay = window.setTimeout(slider, 1000);
        });
        
        function init_slider() {
            $('#pic-1').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                window.clearTimeout(slider_delay);
                slider_delay = window.setTimeout(slider, 1000);
            });
        }
        init_slider();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0; border:0; box-sizing:border-box;font: inherit;}

.slider{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#111;
}
.slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}

.options{
  width:10%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
}

.option{
  width:700px;
  height:18%;
  margin-bottom:9%;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all .5s ease;
}
.option:hover{
 background:#000;
}
.o-rank{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#34495e;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:30px;
}
.o-rank h1{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
}
.o-logo{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.o-logo img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.o-title{
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.o-title h1{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:90px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.o-text{
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
.o-text p{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:left;
}
.o-button{
  width:60px;
  height:40px;
  background:#34495e;
  float:right;
  margin-top:25px;
  text-align:center;
}
.o-button a{
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:24px;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:40px;
}
.pictures{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:10;
}
#pic-1, #pic-2, #pic-3, #pic-4, #pic-5{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.pic img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.p-hov{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:#000;
 z-index:999;
}
#pic-h-1, #pic-h-2, #pic-h-3, #pic-h-4, #pic-h-5{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 visibility:hidden;
 position:absolute
}

.pic-h img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

/* Responsive */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 800px) {
  .slider{
    height:220px;
  }
  .option{
    width:300px;
  }
  .o-rank{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:4px;
  }
  .o-rank h1{
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:15px;
  }
  .o-logo{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:7.5px;
    margin-left:6px;
  }
  .o-title{
    width:70px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
  }
  .o-title h1{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:8px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:40px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  .o-text{
    width:135px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
  }
  .o-text p{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:8px;
    text-align:left;
  }
  .o-button{
    width:30px;
    height:15px;
    background:#34495e;
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .o-button a{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    top:-12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="options">
            <div class="option" id="ref_1">
                <div class="o-rank">
                    <h1> 1 </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="o-logo">
                    <img src="http://www.pazarlamasyon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/BMW_logo.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-title">
                        <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-text">
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-button">
                        <a href="#"> > </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="option" id="ref_2">
                    <div class="o-rank">
                        <h1> 2 </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-logo">
                        <img src="http://www.pazarlamasyon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/BMW_logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-text">
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-button">
                            <a href="#"> > </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" id="ref_3">
                        <div class="o-rank">
                            <h1> 3 </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-logo">
                            <img src="http://www.pazarlamasyon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/BMW_logo.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="o-title">
                                <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="o-text">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="o-button">
                                <a href="#"> > </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option"  id="ref_4">
                            <div class="o-rank">
                                <h1> 4 </h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="o-logo">
                                <img src="http://www.pazarlamasyon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/BMW_logo.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="o-title">
                                    <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="o-text">
                                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="o-button">
                                    <a href="#"> > </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="option"  id="ref_5">
                                <div class="o-rank">
                                    <h1> 5 </h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="o-logo">
                                    <img src="http://www.pazarlamasyon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/BMW_logo.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="o-title">
                                        <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="o-text">
                                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ultrices pellentesque facilisis. </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="o-button">
                                        <a href="#"> > </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pictures">
                                <div class="pic" id="pic-1">
                                    <img src="http://inourvillage.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/placeholder4-1024x768.png" id="tes-1" class="tes" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pic" id="pic-2">
                                        <img src="http://trustedfinance.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-red.png" id="tes-2"  class="tes">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="pic" id="pic-3">
                                            <img src="http://trustedfinance.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-green.png" id="tes-3"  class="tes">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pic" id="pic-4">
                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x768.png/222/fff&text=placeholder" id="tes-4"  class="tes">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="pic" id="pic-5">
                                                    <img src="http://duinccyv5gl5b.cloudfront.net/uploads/2012/04/slide-placeholder-31.png" id="tes-5"  class="tes">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>    
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful, but now when i hover the bullets the slideshow stops all together, is there a way around this?

Comment: does it stay stopped even after you move the mouse off the bullets? I'm using chrome on ubuntu and don't have any other browser set up to test right now

Comment: I'm using chrome as well, when i move the mouse it just stops hovering, also i'm sorry for bugging you, i'm quite new to jQuery

Comment: hmmm not really sure, I can't reproduce that issue... when you load the page try right clicking and clicking inspect element to bring up the developer tools, them you can check the js console to see if there are any errors firing

Comment: if you want it to continue to cycle even if you are still hovering over a bullet you can change `if(!hover){
                next = current.next();
            }else{
                next=$('#pic-'+hover.attr('id').split('_')[1]);
            }` to just `next = current.next();`

Comment: forgot about that one... that tells it to stop cycling while you are hovering over a bullet... the second function in the "hover" call tells it to start again when your mouse moves off the bullet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69918/discussion-between-kiraken-and-trey).

Comment: i isolated the problem to this 'if (!hover) slider_delay = window.setTimeout(slider, 1000);' If i change it to 'if (hover) slider_delay = window.setTimeout(slider, 1000);' after hovering to goes on one extra slide and then stops

Answer (score 0):

Your slider works as what you've coded.
Change    `onmouseover="show1();"` to `onmouseenter="show1();"` if you want it to fade just once.